# Monitor Network usage of a process in android

Tags: android, android-networking

I am developing on a custom Android based platform. I wanted to know if there is a way to monitor the network usage of a process in Android programmatically.

For Example

I have a service which keeps track of all the processes that are running in the device. This service wants also to track information of the network usage of a single process, and if it exceed on a prefixed value, the service force-kills it. Or maybe (it would be better), unless force killing it, it prevents the process from using network.

Since I'm developing in a custom platform so I can give my process any permission that I want, is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use `TrafficStats`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html), either directly or by examining how it is implemented so your custom OS modifications can get at the underlying implementation.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's exactly what i was searching for.